# Make a button visible when service is stopped

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I will do something when service stopped in my app

for example:
i have a countdown code in my service,and then i will when that countdown stopped random button set visible.

i don't know how i can do something by service,i can't set button in service's body so how i can set it?and where i should do it?

in this following code i wrote my countdown in //your code line but i don't know how i can set button visible when count down stopped

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       strong text // your code
        return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is communicate between a running service and an Activity. There are multiple ways to do this. The most easiest would be to pass an event from the service and catch that event in the activity. You can implement it from scratch or use an Event Bus. I would recommend using this library [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus%22EventBus%22). Using this library you can pass an object containing some info (about what happened in the service) to the activity and based on that you can perform the action you need. I'm not posting any code. Please try doing it yourself, it will be a good learning experience.